# Turn an array of React context providers into a nested structure

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a component that takes in an array of React context providers and turns them into a nested structure with `Array.reduce()`:

```
const Nested: React:FC<{ providers: React.FC[] }> = ({ providers, children }) => (
  providers.reverse().reduce((acc, P) => <P>{acc}</P>, <>{children}</>)
);
```

But there seems to be a problem if some provider has dependencies on other outer providers.

The following snippet works just fine.

```
<AuthProvider>
  <UploadProvider>
    <App />
  </UploadProvider>
</AuthProvider>
```

But it doesn't work with the `Nested` component.

```
<Nested providers={[AuthProvider, UploadProvider]}>
  <App />
</Nested>
```

They don't seem equivalent somehow.

Here I have 2 providers, `UploadProvider` and `AuthProvider`, `UploadProvider` depends on `AuthProvider` for its `getAuthAxios()` from `useAuth` hook:

```
const AuthContext = createContext<{ getAuthAxios: (aud: string) => AxiosInstance }>();
export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
export const AuthProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const getAuthAxios = (aud) => ...; // create an Axios instance and attach auth to the header
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={getAuthAxios}>
      { children }
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and

```
const UploadContext = createContext<{ uploader: Uploader }>();
export const useUpload = () => useContext(UploadContext);
export const UploadProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const axios = useAuth().getAuthAxios(); // <--- the interpreter complains `getAuthAxios()` is undefined
  const uploader = ...; // build an uploader with axios
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={uploader}>
      { children }
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Any idea what goes wrong there? Is it because the reducer renders the inner Provider before the outer comes into being?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer the question to myself. I've done some experiments and verified the approach didn't work because the inner components were rendered before the outer contexts were ready. Recursion is able to tackle the issue:

```
export const Nested: React.FC<{ components: React.FC[] }> = ({ components, children }) => {
  if (components.length === 0) return <>{children}</>;
  const C = components[0];
  return (
    <C>
      <Nested components={components.slice(1)}>
        {children}
      </Nested>
    </C>
  );
};
```

Comment: I would improve on this by making the `components` prop a `React.ElementType[]`

Answer (score 0):

The next snippet of code it's extracted from the source code of the library [react-context-slices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-slices). It accepts an array of providers and gives you a unique provider.

```
const composeProviders = (providers) => {
  const NeutralProvider = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;
  return providers.reduce(
    (AccProvider, Provider) =>
      ({ children }) =>
        (
          <Provider>
            <AccProvider>{children}</AccProvider>
          </Provider>
        ),
    NeutralProvider
  );
};
```

I recommend you take a look at this library because it solves the problem of managing state through Context in a React app once for all. With this library you define slices of Context that are fetched through a unique hook, `useSlice`. This is how you do it:

```
// slices.js
import getHookAndProviderFromSlices from "react-context-slices"
export const {useSlice, Provider} = getHookAndProviderFromSlices({
  count: {initialArg: 0},
  // rest of slices of Context you want to define
})
```

```
// app.js
import {useSlice} from "./slices"
const App = () => {
  const [count, useCount] = useSlice("count")
  return <>
    <button onClick={() => setCount(c => c + 1)}>+</button>{count}
  </>
}
```

As you can see it has 0 boilerplate.